# Startup building and mokup

Tags: php, python, mysql, mongodb, startup

since about two years ago, I did find my interest in code (Hardware/Sytems/Web) and now, I've found a project which motivates me a lot (It takes all my free time indeed).

Starting this point and because my project could soon switch from a free time project to a daily job, I'm currently developing a mockup of this project based on PHP/MySQL and JQuery.

Even if I'm a true Python/MongoDB lover and a System Engineer, I did prefer those technologies to build up my mockup because of their simplicity to build a complete functional private stack at home.

I'm pretty advanced on my mockup and it seems to work as I want it.

Now I'm wondering if, about your point of view, would have been better to start to build my mockup using directly the targeted technologies (Python/MongoDB) rather than to use the easy PHP/MySQL couple to do it?

Obviously, because I plan to made this project my daily job, I had to have something visually functionnal to be able to raise a little bit of money, and about me, using an easier stack it's more easy, but I would like to have your feedback on this kind of question.

Comment: Do you have a programming question? As written, this is just asking for opinions, which isn't a good fit for StackOverflow. My opinion is that you've picked the wrong technologies, but you really shouldn't let that influence you as the apps I build aren't the apps you're likely to build, my skills are different than yours, etc.....

Comment: As you said, it's more a question requiring opinions than programming, BUT if you have some interesting point about technologies and apps as it seems to be the case here, don't be afraid to put your examples and/or opinion, I'm always interest by answers and debate, even if they're not fitting my expectation or sensibility.

Answer (score 2):

The idea that PHP/MySQL is easier or simpler than say Python/MongoDB is just inconsistent. 
If you compare for example, Django (the most popular python web framework) with symfony(PHP) you will find that they are almost identical in terms of features and architecture (symfony is actually slightly more complex but also has more very advanced features).

For mockups, if I were you, I would use solely HTML/jQuery/CSS. 
Build your pages just like you would like to have them in your beta version, use jQuery to load sample data written in json. 
That's all you need. You can even find WYSIWYG application to speed up the process.

Later on, you can build the back-end application using either python or php, it won't matter. 
The integration process will be identical, create your models, create the controllers, and use the HTML you already have as templates.

Building your app in php/mysql then convert it to python/mangodb will make you rewrite almost all the code simply because python is so much different from php (easier I would say too, but that's just my opinion) and because mangodb is not a relational database meaning you will have also to rethink partially your architecture.

Comment: I think that your first sentence came from the fact that I didn't not explain myself correctly or with sufficent informations.

I would rather said that PHP is easier to use for me as a raw language (I don't use framework on my mockup to keep things quick to program and I admit it so dirty) and its more easy for me just because I'm more experienced on it (8 years on PHP against almost 3 on python).

Your point of view about not using backend for the demo is quite interesting, I'll do some test on this side too.

The fact is, my mockup have to be personalized, demo data have to be indeed real.

Comment: So to do this I have to be able to retrieve them from an already up to use backend, but once again, I'll keep an eye on your solution, because it's pretty easy to me to implement and do the job quickly.

I do plan to rewrite completely the application using python and MongoDB as soon as I've reach a sufficient amount of money to be daily focus on my app, but I'll try to build a server this week-end based on Python and MongoDB and rewrite the main page to compare which technology is fastest based on my experience (coding xp I mean).

Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!